# Prevent child's state from reset after parent component state changes also get the values of all child components:ReactJS+ Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, setstate, react-table

I am a bit new to react and I am stuck in this situation where I am implementing custom dropdown filter for a table in react. I have set of dropdown values for each column and there is a Apply button.

I have maintained a child component for this which takes in drop down values  and sends the selected one's back to parent. Then I call a back-end API that gives me filtered data which in-turn sets parents state . The problem here is the checkbox values inside dropdown is lost after I get the data and set the parent state.

Each child components has as a set of checkboxes , an Apply and a clear button. So on click of Apply , I have to send the checked one's to the parent or in general whichever the checked one's without losing the previous content.

I am unable to understand why am I losing the checkbox values?

It would be of great help if someone can help me out with this

Sand box: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-elgamal-0zztb

I have added the sandbox link with proper comments. Please have a look. I am a bit new to react.

Help would be really appreciated

### Parent

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import ReactTable from "react-table";
import "./styles.css";
import "react-table/react-table.css";
import Child from "./Child";
interface IState {
  data: {}[];
  columns: {}[];
  selectedValues: {};
  optionsForColumns: {};
}

interface IProps {}

export default class App extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {

  // Here I have  hardcoded the values, but data and optionsForColumns comes from the backend and it is set inside componentDidMount
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [
        { firstName: "Jack", status: "Submitted", age: "14" },
        { firstName: "Simon", status: "Pending", age: "15" }
      ],
      selectedValues: {},
      columns: [],
      optionsForColumns: {
        firstName: [{ Jack: "4" }, { Simon: "5" }],
        status: [{ Submitted: "5" }, { Pending: "7" }]
      }
    };
  }

  // Get the values for checkboxes that will be sent to child
  getValuesFromKey = (key: any) => {
    let data: any = this.state.optionsForColumns[key];
    let result = data.map((value: any) => {
      let keys = Object.keys(value);
      return {
        field: keys[0],
        checked: false
      };
    });
    return result;
  };

  // Get the consolidated values from child and then pass it for server side filtering
  handleFilter = (fieldName: any, selectedValue: any, modifiedObj: any) => 
  {
    this.setState(
      {
        selectedValues: {
          ...this.state.selectedValues,
          [fieldName]: selectedValue
        }
      },
      () => this.handleColumnFilter(this.state.selectedValues)
    );
  };

  // Function that will make server call based on the checked values from child
  handleColumnFilter = (values: any) => {
    // server side code for filtering
    // After this checkbox content is lost
  };

  // Function where I configure the columns array for the table . (Also data and column fiter values will be set here, in this case I have hardcoded inside constructor)
  componentDidMount() {
    let columns = [
      {
        Header: () => (
          <div>
            <div>
              <Child
                key="firstName"
                name="firstName"
                options={this.getValuesFromKey("firstName")}
                handleFilter={this.handleFilter}
              />
            </div>
            <span>First Name</span>
          </div>
        ),
        accessor: "firstName"
      },
      {
        Header: () => (
          <div>
            <div>
              <Child
                key="status"
                name="status"
                options={this.getValuesFromKey("status")}
                handleFilter={this.handleFilter}
              />
            </div>
            <span>Status</span>
          </div>
        ),
        accessor: "status",
      },
      {
        Header: "Age",
        accessor: "age"
      }
    ];
    this.setState({ columns });
  }

  //Rendering the data table
  render() {
    const { data, columns } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <ReactTable
          data={data}
          columns={columns}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

### Child

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Button, Checkbox, Icon } from "semantic-ui-react";
interface IProps {
  options: any;
  name: string;
  handleFilter(val1: any, val2: any, val3: void): void;
}
interface IState {
  showList: boolean;
  selected: [];
  checkboxOptions: any;
}
export default class Child extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selected: [],
      showList: false,
      checkboxOptions: this.props.options.map((option: any) => option.checked)
    };
  }

  // Checkbox change handler
  handleValueChange = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>, data: any) => {
    const i = this.props.options.findIndex(
      (item: any) => item.field === data.name
    );
    const optionsArr = this.state.checkboxOptions.map(
      (prevState: any, si: any) => (si === i ? !prevState : prevState)
    );
    this.setState({ checkboxOptions: optionsArr });
  };

  //Passing the checked values back to parent
  passSelectionToParent = (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const result = this.props.options.map((item: any, i: any) =>
      Object.assign({}, item, {
        checked: this.state.checkboxOptions[i]
      })
    );
    const selected = result
      .filter((res: any) => res.checked)
      .map((ele: any) => ele.field);
    console.log(selected);
    this.props.handleFilter(this.props.name, selected, result);
  };

  //Show/Hide filter
  toggleList = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ showList: !prevState.showList }));
  };

  //Rendering the checkboxes based on the local state, but still it gets lost after filtering happens
  render() {
    let { showList } = this.state;
    let visibleFlag: string;
    if (showList === true) visibleFlag = "visible";
    else visibleFlag = "";
    return (
      <div>
        <div style={{ position: "absolute" }}>
          <div
            className={"ui scrolling dropdown column-settings " + visibleFlag}
          >
            <Icon className="filter" onClick={this.toggleList} />
            <div className={"menu transition " + visibleFlag}>
              <div className="menu-item-holder">
                {this.props.options.map((item: any, i: number) => (
                  <div className="menu-item" key={i}>
                    <Checkbox
                      name={item.field}
                      onChange={this.handleValueChange}
                      label={item.field}
                      checked={this.state.checkboxOptions[i]}
                    />
                  </div>
                ))}
              </div>
              <div className="menu-btn-holder">
                <Button size="small" onClick={this.passSelectionToParent}>
                  Apply
                </Button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Add each received value to a parent's state array?

Comment: In stackblitz link above, the checkbox content is not lost as I see.

Comment: @Munim Munna, yes I have not added the server side code.. After filtered days comes back, the checkbox values are lost

Comment: [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-meadow-0ecld) I have set `data` with a timeout, still the checkbox values persist.

Comment: See the link I have posted above, modifying the `data` in your `handleColumnFilter` method does not reset the checkboxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a case of state being managed in an inconvenient way. Currently, the state is managed at the Child level, but it would be easier to manage at the Parent level. This is known as [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) in React.

The gist - the shared state is managed in the Parent component, and it's updated by calling a function passed to the Child component. When Apply is clicked, the selected radio value is passed up to the Parent, which merges the new selection into the shared state.

I have created a minimal example of your code, showing how we can lift state up from the Child to the Parent component. I'm also using a few new-ish features of React, like `useState` to simplify the Child component.

```js
// Child Component
const Child = ({name, options, updateSelections}) => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState([]);
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    let updated;
    if (event.target.checked) {
      updated = [...selected, event.target.value];
    } else {
      updated = selected.filter(v => v !== event.target.value);
    }
    setSelected(updated);
  }
  
  const passSelectionToParent = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    updateSelections(name, selected);
  }

  return (
    <form>
      {options.map(item => (
        <label for={name}>
          <input
            key={name}
            type="checkbox"
            name={item}
            value={item}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          {item}
        </label>
      ))}
      <button onClick={passSelectionToParent}>Apply</button>
    </form>
  )
}

// Parent Component
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.fields = ["firstName", "status"],
    this.state = {
      selected: {}
    };
  }
  
  getValuesFromKey = (data, key) => {
    return data.map(item => item[key]);
  }
  
  updateSelections = (name, selection) => {
    this.setState({
      selected: {...this.state.selected, [name]: selection}
    }, () => console.log(this.state.selected));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.fields.map(field => (
          <Child
            key={field}
            name={field}
            options={this.getValuesFromKey(this.props.data, field)} 
            updateSelections={this.updateSelections}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const data = [
  { firstName: "Jack", status: "Submitted" },
  { firstName: "Simon", status: "Pending" },
  { firstName: "Pete", status: "Approved" },
  { firstName: "Lucas", status: "Rejected" }
];

ReactDOM.render(<Parent data={data}/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.7.0-alpha.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.7.0-alpha.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I'm more than happy to help point you in the right direction, but I would be doing a disservice to you if I did your work for you.

Comment: Yes, if the `fetch` was done in the Parent component, then updates to the data could be passed down to the Child component.

Comment: But in that case, checkbox value will not be retained right , It will always be reset to the initial value after click on apply?

Comment: You would need to use a controlled input (see docs for an explanation of this) to set the 'checked' attribute of each input based on the state.

Comment: The issue you're having now is different from the original question you asked (and we resolved). I can see the state is correctly keeping all the selected options in your current version. Can you explain what's not working?

Comment: This is a different issue than we resolved previously. Retracting the accepted solution for this reason is, imo, frowned upon, but we'll try to resolve this quickly. Unfortunately I'm not able to replicate the issue you're describing, the checkboxes keep their checked state for me. Can you describe the issue in more detail?

Comment: @ Brett DeWoody The issue that I am facing is , after I click on Apply of a particular dropdown, I make an API call that takes these checked values and gives me filtered data . Now next time I open the same dropdown, I would want the previously checked values . Don't know what is causing this issue

Comment: It appears you're maintaining a `checked` state within your Child component, and that `checked` state is used to control the value of the checkbox - `checked={this.state.checkboxOptions[i]`. The initial `this.state.checkboxOptions` comes from the `options` prop, which comes from `getValuesFromKey`, and within `getValuesFromKey` you've set the `checked` prop to `false`. So it's always setting the `checked` attribute to `false`.

Comment: Instead of setting `checked: false`, you need the value of `checked` to depend on the selected options. If the option has been selected, you want `checked: true`.

Comment: But initial value would go undefined right? It would really really helpful if you could just edit the snippet or give a similar kind edit

Comment: I always try to teach how to solve an issue, rather than give a fix. The value of `checked` would be `true` if that option has been selected, or `false` otherwise.

Comment: You're really close. It's just that you've hardcoded `checked: false`, which then gets passed through to the checkbox and sets `checked=false` on the checkbox.

Comment: @ Brett DeWoody But here I am not maintaining a state variable in the parent right that will map the checked one's inside the parent . How will I read it from child?

Comment: But that's what you're doing - you have a `checked` property in an object within `getValuesFromKey`, which gets passed to the child, and used as the `checked` attribute of the input. Here's a quick example, change line 42 of index.tsx to `checked: true`, and you'll notice all the checkboxes are now checked by default.

Comment: Yes I got that. Now you mean to say call getColumnFilterValues() after filtering to update the value?

Comment: The problem is that React is calling `getColumnFilterValues()` when the data changes, and because `getColumnFilterValues()` contains `checked: false`, the checkboxes are being reset to the unchecked position. You need to change `getColumnFilterValues()` so `checked: false` is something like `checked: isThisValueSelected ? true : false`

Comment: You could also maybe remove `checked: false`, and the `checked` prop from the `<input />`

Answer (score 1):

Your checkbox values are only lost when you hide/show the table, as the table goes out of
DOM the state of it and it's children are lost. When the table is mounted to DOM, `Child`
component is mounted again initializing a new state taking checkbox values from
`getValuesFromKey` method of which returns false by default clearing checkbox ticks.

```
return {
  field: keys[0],
  checked: false
};
```

[Stackblitz reproducing the issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-meadow-0ecld).

You have to set checkbox values checking the `selectedValues` object to see if it was selected.

```
return {
  field: keys[0],
  checked: this.state.selectedValues[key] && this.state.selectedValues[key].includes(keys[0]),
};
```